# How to access errno after using syscall?

Tags: c, system-calls, stat, errno

I'm using syscall `stat`, it returns 0/-1. When -1 is returned it means, error occurred and errno is set as it should be (source: `man 2 stat`).

But I want to access errno and print it, how to do that?

Comment: First of all, you're not using the `stat` syscall - but the libc wrapper for that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it from [errno](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html).

Also you can print the error using [strerror](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strerror.3.html)

Comment: is errno a variable? Can I just do `int er = errno;` ?

Comment: Yes. Act as if it's a "global variable" declared in `errno.h` with the type of `int`, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/error/errno . Sometimes it's a macro. Sometimes it's a `extern int errno;`. Depends on platform.

Comment: Thanks! It helped! ;)

Comment: Yes, you can save the value as int.